Can't run several test at once using Testcontainers and Database Rider
I want to test persisting layer in my Spring Boot project with Database Rider and Testcontainers.
When I run my test classes separately, everything works fine.
But, when I run all my tests at once, the error is occurred:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create dataset for test 'shouldFindUserById'.

Could you please help me to resolve this error?

Here is source code of my project - https://github.com/stack-overflow-qna/jpa-testcontainer-dbrider-tests
Commands to run separate test classes:
./mvnw test -Dtest=UserRepositoryTest
./mvnw test -Dtest=BlogPostRepositoryTest

Command to run all tests:
./mvnw test

Test classes:
package com.romach007.jpa_test.blog_post.repository;

import com.github.database.rider.core.api.dataset.DataSet;
import com.github.database.rider.junit5.api.DBRider;
import com.romach007.jpa_test.entity.BlogPostEntity;
import com.romach007.jpa_test.repository.BlogPostRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.ServiceConnection;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;

import java.util.UUID;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@DBRider
@Testcontainers
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class BlogPostRepositoryTest {
    @ServiceConnection
    @Container
    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> container = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:16.1");

    @Autowired
    private BlogPostRepository blogPostRepository;

    @Test
    @DataSet("datasets/blogPosts.yml")
    public void shouldFindBlogPostById() {
        // Given
        BlogPostEntity expectedBlogPost = new BlogPostEntity();
        expectedBlogPost.setId(UUID.fromString("2eff530f-5f91-402d-89c7-c4f3099c9833"));
        expectedBlogPost.setContent("Test content");

        // When
        BlogPostEntity actualBlogPost = blogPostRepository.findBlogPostById(UUID.fromString("2eff530f-5f91-402d-89c7-c4f3099c9833")).orElse(null);

        // Then
        assertEquals(expectedBlogPost, actualBlogPost);
    }
}

package com.romach007.jpa_test.blog_post.repository;

import com.github.database.rider.core.api.configuration.DBUnit;
import com.github.database.rider.core.api.dataset.DataSet;
import com.github.database.rider.junit5.api.DBRider;
import com.romach007.jpa_test.entity.UserEntity;
import com.romach007.jpa_test.repository.UserRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.ServiceConnection;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;

import java.util.UUID;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@DBRider
//@DBUnit(caseSensitiveTableNames = true, escapePattern = "\"")
@Testcontainers
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class UserRepositoryTest {
    @ServiceConnection
    @Container
    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> container = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:16.1");

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    @DataSet("datasets/users.yml")
    public void shouldFindUserById() {
        // Given
        UserEntity expectedUser = new UserEntity();
        expectedUser.setId(UUID.fromString("2eff530f-5f91-402d-89c7-c4f3099c9833"));
        expectedUser.setName("User");

        // When
        UserEntity actualUser = userRepository.findUserById(UUID.fromString("2eff530f-5f91-402d-89c7-c4f3099c9833")).orElse(null);

        // Then
        assertEquals(expectedUser, actualUser);
    }
}

Error while running all tests (using command ./mvnw test):
2024-04-14T02:40:10.479+03:00  WARN 72228 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@19710bd9 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:394) ~[postgresql-42.7.1.jar:42.7.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:498) ~[postgresql-42.7.1.jar:42.7.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:415) ~[postgresql-42.7.1.jar:42.7.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:335) ~[postgresql-42.7.1.jar:42.7.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:321) ~[postgresql-42.7.1.jar:42.7.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:297) ~[postgresql-42.7.1.jar:42.7.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:246) ~[postgresql-42.7.1.jar:42.7.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgDatabaseMetaData.getTables(PgDatabaseMetaData.java:1377) ~[postgresql-42.7.1.jar:42.7.1]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyDatabaseMetaData.getTables(ProxyDatabaseMetaData.java:67) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyDatabaseMetaData.getTables(HikariProxyDatabaseMetaData.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at org.dbunit.database.DefaultMetadataHandler.tableExists(DefaultMetadataHandler.java:119) ~[dbunit-2.7.3.jar:na]
        at org.dbunit.database.search.AbstractMetaDataBasedSearchCallback.getNodes(AbstractMetaDataBasedSearchCallback.java:184) ~[dbunit-2.7.3.jar:na]
        at org.dbunit.database.search.AbstractMetaDataBasedSearchCallback.getNodes(AbstractMetaDataBasedSearchCallback.java:149) ~[dbunit-2.7.3.jar:na]
        at org.dbunit.database.search.AbstractMetaDataBasedSearchCallback.getNodesFromImportedKeys(AbstractMetaDataBasedSearchCallback.java:99) ~[dbunit-2.7.3.jar:na]
        at org.dbunit.database.search.ImportedKeysSearchCallback.getEdges(ImportedKeysSearchCallback.java:53) ~[dbunit-2.7.3.jar:na]
        at org.dbunit.util.search.DepthFirstSearch.reverseSearch(DepthFirstSearch.java:264) ~[dbunit-2.7.3.jar:na]
        at org.dbunit.util.search.DepthFirstSearch.search(DepthFirstSearch.java:148) ~[dbunit-2.7.3.jar:na]
        at org.dbunit.util.search.DepthFirstSearch.search(DepthFirstSearch.java:104) ~[dbunit-2.7.3.jar:na]
        at org.dbunit.database.search.TablesDependencyHelper.getDependentTables(TablesDependencyHelper.java:91) ~[dbunit-2.7.3.jar:na]
        at org.dbunit.database.search.TablesDependencyHelper.getDependentTables(TablesDependencyHelper.java:72) ~[dbunit-2.7.3.jar:na]
        at com.github.database.rider.core.api.dataset.RiderSequenceFilter.getDependencyInfo(RiderSequenceFilter.java:175) ~[rider-core-1.42.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.database.rider.core.api.dataset.RiderSequenceFilter.sortTableNames(RiderSequenceFilter.java:68) ~[rider-core-1.42.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.database.rider.core.api.dataset.RiderSequenceFilter.<init>(RiderSequenceFilter.java:34) ~[rider-core-1.42.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.database.rider.core.dataset.DataSetExecutorImpl.performSequenceFiltering(DataSetExecutorImpl.java:323) ~[rider-core-1.42.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.database.rider.core.dataset.DataSetExecutorImpl.createDataSet(DataSetExecutorImpl.java:129) ~[rider-core-1.42.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.database.rider.core.RiderRunner.runBeforeTest(RiderRunner.java:44) ~[rider-core-1.42.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.database.rider.junit5.DBUnitExtension.beforeTestExecution(DBUnitExtension.java:69) ~[rider-junit5-1.42.0.jar:na]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks$5(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:192) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:203) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:203) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:191) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:47) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:56) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:148) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:122) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385) ~[surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162) ~[surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507) ~[surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495) ~[surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:467) ~[postgresql-42.7.1.jar:42.7.1]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2154) ~[postgresql-42.7.1.jar:42.7.1]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:367) ~[postgresql-42.7.1.jar:42.7.1]
        ... 81 common frames omitted

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.440 s <<< FAILURE! -- in com.romach007.jpa_test.blog_post.repository.UserRepositoryTest
[ERROR] com.romach007.jpa_test.blog_post.repository.UserRepositoryTest.shouldFindUserById -- Time elapsed: 0.019 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create dataset for test 'shouldFindUserById'.
        at com.github.database.rider.core.RiderRunner.runBeforeTest(RiderRunner.java:46)
        at com.github.database.rider.junit5.DBUnitExtension.beforeTestExecution(DBUnitExtension.java:69)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
Caused by: com.github.database.rider.core.exception.DataBaseSeedingException: Could not initialize dataset: datasets/users.yml
        at com.github.database.rider.core.dataset.DataSetExecutorImpl.createDataSet(DataSetExecutorImpl.java:142)
        at com.github.database.rider.core.RiderRunner.runBeforeTest(RiderRunner.java:44)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.dbunit.dataset.DataSetException: Exception while searching the dependent tables.
        at com.github.database.rider.core.api.dataset.RiderSequenceFilter.sortTableNames(RiderSequenceFilter.java:72)
        at com.github.database.rider.core.api.dataset.RiderSequenceFilter.<init>(RiderSequenceFilter.java:34)
        at com.github.database.rider.core.dataset.DataSetExecutorImpl.performSequenceFiltering(DataSetExecutorImpl.java:323)
        at com.github.database.rider.core.dataset.DataSetExecutorImpl.createDataSet(DataSetExecutorImpl.java:129)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.dbunit.util.search.SearchException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
        at org.dbunit.database.search.AbstractMetaDataBasedSearchCallback.getNodes(AbstractMetaDataBasedSearchCallback.java:221)
        at org.dbunit.database.search.AbstractMetaDataBasedSearchCallback.getNodes(AbstractMetaDataBasedSearchCallback.java:149)
        at org.dbunit.database.search.AbstractMetaDataBasedSearchCallback.getNodesFromImportedKeys(AbstractMetaDataBasedSearchCallback.java:99)
        at org.dbunit.database.search.ImportedKeysSearchCallback.getEdges(ImportedKeysSearchCallback.java:53)
        at org.dbunit.util.search.DepthFirstSearch.reverseSearch(DepthFirstSearch.java:264)
        at org.dbunit.util.search.DepthFirstSearch.search(DepthFirstSearch.java:148)
        at org.dbunit.util.search.DepthFirstSearch.search(DepthFirstSearch.java:104)
        at org.dbunit.database.search.TablesDependencyHelper.getDependentTables(TablesDependencyHelper.java:91)
        at org.dbunit.database.search.TablesDependencyHelper.getDependentTables(TablesDependencyHelper.java:72)
        at com.github.database.rider.core.api.dataset.RiderSequenceFilter.getDependencyInfo(RiderSequenceFilter.java:175)
        at com.github.database.rider.core.api.dataset.RiderSequenceFilter.sortTableNames(RiderSequenceFilter.java:68)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:394)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:498)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:415)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:335)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:321)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:297)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:246)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgDatabaseMetaData.getTables(PgDatabaseMetaData.java:1377)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyDatabaseMetaData.getTables(ProxyDatabaseMetaData.java:67)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyDatabaseMetaData.getTables(HikariProxyDatabaseMetaData.java)
        at org.dbunit.database.DefaultMetadataHandler.tableExists(DefaultMetadataHandler.java:119)
        at org.dbunit.database.search.AbstractMetaDataBasedSearchCallback.getNodes(AbstractMetaDataBasedSearchCallback.java:184)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:467)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2154)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:367)
        ... 28 more

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   UserRepositoryTest.shouldFindUserById » Runtime Could not create dataset for test 'shouldFindUserById'.
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.035 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-14T02:40:11+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.1.2:test (default-test) on project jpa_test: 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/romancherepanov/Projects/stack-overflow/jpa-testcontainer-dbrider-tests/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException


The solution is to add cacheConnection: false parameter to Database Rider configuration:
dbunit.yml:
cacheConnection: false
properties:
  caseSensitiveTableNames: true
  escapePattern: '"'

